# Manually entering a password

Tags: shell-script

The script is working:

```
#!/bin/sh


echo "Enter Server IP Address"
read IP
echo 'mypassword' | sudo -S ssh $IP </home/myscript.sh
```

How do I modify it so I can manually enter the IP address, and then mypassword?

Comment: How do I modify it so I can manually enter the IP address, and then mypassword?

Answer (score 1):

You can either prompt the user to enter a password:

```
#!/bin/sh 

printf "Enter Server IP Address: "
read IP

printf "Enter Server Password: "
read -s PASSWORD

echo "$PASSWORD" | sudo -S ssh $IP
```

NOTE: The `-s` option in `read` will not echo the users input. Therefore, you can enter in a password without having to worry about others being able to read in your terminal.

Or have it entered in through a command line argument:

```
#!/bin/sh

usage() {
    echo "$0 [IP] [PASSWORD]"
    exit 1
}

if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    IP=$1
    PASSWORD=$2
else
    usage
fi

echo "$PASSWORD" | sudo -S ssh $IP
```

Answer (score 1):

the `read` command prompts the user for input, and this input can be stored in a variable. This is seen on line 3 of your script `read IP`. So in order to take in another variable you just need another `read` for another variable.

A clean suggestion:

```
#!/bin/sh
read -p "Enter Server IP Address: " IP
read -s -p "Enter your Password: " PASSWORD
echo "$PASSWORD" | sudo -S ssh $IP </home/myscript.sh
```

The `-p` in the read command stands for prompt, and lets you output a message before taking in input. The `-s` prevents the user's typing from being shown, so that a person looking over your shoulder can't see what you type.